# Ionic 2 Native Google Maps - "plugin is not defined"

Tags: cordova, google-maps, angular, cordova-plugins, ionic2

I installed the plugin by running

```
ionic plugin add cordova-plugin-googlemaps --variable API_KEY_FOR_IOS="YOUR_IOS_API_KEY_IS_HERE"
```

but I get the following error:

```
ReferenceError: plugin is not defined
at new GoogleMap (googlemaps.js:55)
at SingleMap.initMap (single-map.ts:27)
...
```

My usage code is pretty straight forward, too

```
let map = new GoogleMap(`map-${this.accomodation.slug}`);
```

I tested it while under `ionic serve` and it does not work. It's really weird. I've tried everything and I don't know what to do.

My ionic versions:

```
"ionic-angular": "2.0.0-beta.11",
"ionic-native": "1.2.4",
```

Answer (score 0):

Has you followed this http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/native/google-maps/?

Try use this repo as example: https://github.com/Petronetto/ionic2GMapNative

Answer (score -1):

Edit: ok, that was really easy to solve: test it on real device, it should be ok.
(I forgot about it...)

I have the same issue, the doc didn't provide any help in this case. Follow it and your app will fail with exception 'plugin is not defined'.

If someone can help it will be really appreciated !

Comment: I just included google maps api normally up until I find a solution (a `<script>` tag within my index.html). I'll deal with it later for sure. I wasted some time trying to make it work, so I'm just gonna leave it as the last thing on the list.. By moving on I gained more time, cause the client could see some change.

Comment: Yes, my apologize. My first intention was to comment Juliano's answer.